# SharePoint list sent alert to Ad group

Tags: sharepoint, alert

I have a SharePoint 2013 on-prem  list, want to sent default item change alert to AD email group(distribution list).
I am alloweded only SharePoint users in the people picker, in ootb alert setting.

Is there is any ootb way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Gokul

Comment: It is important to mention the version of sharepoint that you're using. For instance, if you're using Sharepoint Online, you can use Microsoft Flows for doing this task. Take a look to the webpage, your solution would consist on add the event "When an existing item is modified" then do the task "Send Email". https://flow.microsoft.com

Comment: Hi Brank, I am using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. Is there is any way in ootb.

Comment: Then you can create a workflow for the list using Sharepoint Designer